# how to create a another set of array?

Tags: jquery

I'm slowly understand creating an array, and now I don't understand why the values only adding on previous array and not creating another array to add the values if I add another td.
this sample what I want.
[apple, 2, red and round]
[orange,1, sweet]

and
result of the code
[apple, 2, red and round, orange, 1, sweet]

code:

```js
var $item =     $('input[name ="Item"]')
var $quantity = $('input[name ="Quantity"]')
var $desc =     $('input[name ="Description"]')

var itemarray;


$(document).on('change',"tbody.tbody td input#firsttable",function (){
    itemarray = $(".tbody td input#firsttable")
    .get()
    .map(function (input){
        return input.value
    })
    console.log(itemarray)
})
$(document).on('click','.item-add-onclick', function (){
    var cols = "";
    var col = "";
    
    cols += `<tr><td>
                <input type="text" name="Item" id="firsttable" value required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="Quantity" id="firsttable" value required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Description" id="firsttable" value required>
            </td></tr>`
$("tbody.tbody").append(cols);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Item</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Item" id="firsttable" value required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="Quantity" id="firsttable" value required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Description" id="firsttable" value required>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary item-add-onclick" id="addrow">Add</button>
                </td>
                
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **ID should be unique** .So I changed all `id="firsttable"` to `class="firsttable"`

2nd : mapping/looping through the inputs will return all the inputs values in array ..So You need to loop through the `tr` first

Try the next code

```js
var $item =     $('input[name ="Item"]')
var $quantity = $('input[name ="Quantity"]')
var $desc =     $('input[name ="Description"]')

var itemarray;


$(document).on('change',"tbody.tbody td input.firsttable",function (){
    itemarray = [];
    $(".tbody tr").each(function(i , v){
      itemarray[i] = $(this).find('input.firsttable').get()
      .map(function (input){
          return input.value
      });
    });
    console.log(itemarray)
})
$(document).on('click','.item-add-onclick', function (){
    var cols = "";
    var col = "";
    
    cols += `<tr><td>
                <input type="text" name="Item" class="firsttable" value required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="Quantity" class="firsttable" value required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Description" class="firsttable" value required>
            </td></tr>`;
     $('tbody').append(cols);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Description</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="Item" class="firsttable" value required>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="number" name="Quantity" class="firsttable" value required>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="Description" class="firsttable" value required>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary item-add-onclick" id="addrow">Add</button>
          </td>

      </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```